# Showing bookmark extents as empty, black out-lined boxes? Specifically in a map frame on a layout page in ArcGIS Pro 2.8

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, bookmarks, map-series

I've created a bunch of bookmarks in ArcGIS Pro 2.8.0, and want to figure out a way to get the extent of each bookmark to appear as a black box around the area on a layout for a map series I created. Can I use the drawing tool to create the shapes as I zoom to each bookmark, then join all the shapes as a layer? How would I go about this if so? I know about extent indicator, but that only shows the current map frame, whereas I want to show all bookmarks on the overview map. If possible one will be a different color to highlight the current page it represents.

The final goal is to create a map series of pages, where each page contains two map frames: 1) frame of study area, and 2) overview of entire area, with each study area outlined by black box. That second map frame is what I'm having trouble with figuring out how to show all bookmark extents on.

Comment: You should be able to create a polygon feature class from your bookmarks by reading their extents and names.  I'm pretty sure there's example code to do this in the help on ArcPy.